# How to set nullable on association in Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

Lets say I have a `League` entity and a `User` entity and I want the manager (`User`) of that league to be mandatory. How can I tell `Sequelize` that there should be a not-null constraint on the `League.ManagerId` column?

Here is how I defined my association:

`League.belongsTo User, {as: 'Manager'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify `foreignKey` (see [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/associations/) and [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/)) property:

```js
League.belongsTo(User, {
    as: 'creator',
    foreignKey: {
        name:  'league',
        allowNull: false
    }
});
```